# Does the number of samples, as opposed to the sample size in each sample, matter for the Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, intuition

(1)So here is a formula that describes CLT I found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem.

[image: from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem]

According to the first part of the explanation, n as in Xn describes the number of samples(i.e. how many times we samples)we draw from the population.

However, according to my understanding of the CLT, the distribution of sample statistics approaches normal when we increase the sample size. If we bring that idea into the formula, the n in the Z formula and the standard error of the means formulas should both describe the sample size.

Given the above, I fail to reconcile that n represents the same thing in this formula. If it is the sample size, how can I interpret the first line? If it's the number of samples we take, how does it match the definition of CLT?

(2)Going off of the previous question, I wonder if the number of samples matter for CLT? We all know that optimally having a sample size=30 can let us pass and proceed to assume normality due to CLT. However, what if I limit my sample size to 2(small sample size), and get 10,000(large number of samples)of such samples? Could I still assume a normal distribution - does CLT apply in this situation?

Comment: This is a baffling question.  What is a "time of sampling" and how does it differ from a sample size?  Your quotation makes no reference to a "time" and neither AFAIK does any standard statement of the CLT.

Comment: I just reworded it. The "times of sampling" is supposed to express the number of samples. For example, we can get 10 samples, each with sample size=30, or we could get 100 samples, each with sample size=30 - the latter has a larger number of samples(100) than the former(10) while their sample sizes are the same(30). I failed to find a better word for this, but if there is one please let me know.

Comment: The quotation is a part of the wikipedia of the CLT(link attached). My confusion is precisely how the formula can be connected to the statement of CLT, and how shall I understand the n in the formula in the context of CLT.

Comment: The CLT is a statement about what happens as the sample size increases.  Obtaining different samples of the same size is not relevant to it.  This Wikipedia quotation is using the word "sample" to refer to a single *observation.*  Thus, $\bar X_n = (X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n)/n.$  You might find it helpful to read some of our [more popular threads on the CLT](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=central%20limit%20theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So can I take this as n samples, each with sample size =1(one single observation), thus the sample size is also equal to n? Or shall I see it as one single sample with n elements in it?

Comment: Please read the other threads on the CLT: they will make all this perfectly clear.